# How to add a reference to a js file in a SWF HTML wrapper?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex

I'm working with Flash Builder and have the HTML file containing the SWF file generated automatically upon compilation. Now I want to add a reference to a js file (with  tag), but it's deleted every time the file is recreated. How can I include it as part of the creation?
Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used Flash Builder in a few years, but I recall that the generated file is built from a template that should be part of your project files. You should be able to edit that template, I just don't recall the location.

Answer (score 0):

Every time Flash Builder compiles the project it will generate default html file containing the SWF reference with standard other stuff. It seems you have added reference to some other JS file that gets overwritten. Now you have two solutions:

1. You can turn off "Generated HTML Wrapper File" in Project Settings. This will delete the auto-generated HTML wrapper file in your bin directory. If you need to keep it, make a copy first and put it back after turning off this option.
2. But if you don't like this option then what you are looking for is to edit the HTML wrapper template. For that you need to understand various tokens used in the template. You can read about it [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf663fe-7fff.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ba5) and [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ba8.html).